# Sending HTTP POST in curl format with C#

Tags: curl, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to build an application that will post data to Facebook Graph API without using the libcurl,
The problem is this:

```
curl --silent --location
 -F "type=25"
 -F "action_spec={'action.type':'app_use', 'application':195713270451234}"
 "https://graph.facebook.com/act_12345678/adcreatives?access_token=____"
```

Now I know -F specifies HTTP POST var values but I have no clue how to send this format:

```
-F "action_spec={'action.type':'app_use', 'application':195713270451234}
```

If anyone could give me a clue about how to convert it to a simple HTTP POST request it'd be awesome.
I will be glad to know if there's a way to send the whole curl request string as a request!

Answer (score 2):

Golden rule:

- treat key-value pair json objects as `IDictionary<string, object>` or `IDictionary<string, dynamic>` or anonymous objects.
- treat json arrays as `IList<object>` or `IList<dynamic>`
- treat others as json types as primitive objects as `bool`, `string`, `long`, `double` and so on.

Here is the sample code:

```
var actionSpec = new Dictionary<string,object>();
actionSpec["action.type"] = "app_use";
actionSpec["application"] = 195713270451234;

var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic result = fb.Post("act_12345678/adcreatives", new { type = 25, action_spec = actionSpec });
```

Comment: I want to send the HTTP request by myself and don't reside on the Facebook SDK